# Copy a row into a column from different files Excel

Tags: excel, csv, xls, vba

i need to copy some elements of a row from a file to some different cells in another file.
This is the starting file:

```
output.csv
I_30_2_02_02_1.csv  7   239
I_30_2_02_02_1.csv  7   174
I_30_2_02_02_1.csv  7   458
I_30_2_02_02_1.csv  7   156
I_30_2_02_02_1.csv  7   163
```

This is the ending file:

```
Results.xls
I_30_2_02_02_1.csv      7   239 7   174 7   458 7   156 7   163
```

I have to do this 900 times

Do you know how can I do this? I tried paste special but it duplicates elements.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want to paste those values 7,239,..., so on in one row itself. But if that assumption is correct, and assuming your data is in Sheet4, the formula to be used in cell B2 is (for getting the first 7)

```
=INDEX(Sheet4!$B$1:$C$12,TRUNC(COLUMN()/2),MOD(COLUMN(),2)+1)
```

You can drag the formula across for 900 columns. A1 in your XLS can be linked to A1 in CSV directly.

This should give you all the values in one row.

See sample screenshot of the excel file attached. Values are re-pasted below for illustrative purposes only.
[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qNnO.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qNnO.png)

Note: The formula in the Index function $B$1:$C$12 can be generalised to $B:$C, if you aren't sure about the no of your entries.

Comment: so I have to create a sheet4 where i copy the data contained in output.csv?

Comment: Nope, sheet4 was my sheet corresponding to your sheet in the CSV file. You will need to get the complete address to the sheet in your CSV file into this formula. The answer assumes my data was in Sheet 4. For your data, it needs your path. The easiest way is to start typing this formula by yourself in your Excel file and direct it to your CSV whereever I have written Sheet 4.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to loop through all.csv files in a directory. Add in your specific string manipulation or whatever into the middle section. Add a comment if you need help on that too...

```
'KMZ 02/05/20105
Option Explicit

Private Sub whatever()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all specified filetypes in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

'typical excel variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'classic loopers
Dim i, j, k As Long

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder - {Where your *.csv's are saved...}"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.csv"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    Debug.Print "myFile = " & myFile
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Do your stuff here, man.
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            'add in your string manipulation / cell dumping here
            'with a few lines


        End With


      'Close opened *.csv, do not save
      wb.Saved = True  'fake a save, so message box doesnt pop up
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

      'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete! Review in your xlWorkbook!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I've got only one csv file containing rows like output.csv and I have to put them as columns in results.xls, after the first five rows i have other rows like I_30_... 7 234 ecc